Using conditional probabilities, calculate $P(ξ < η < ζ)$
Let $ξ$, $η$ and $ζ$ be independent random variables uniformly distributed on the interval [0, 1]. Using conditional probabilities, calculate $P(ξ < η < ζ)$.
What I did:
$P(ξ < η < ζ) = P(ξ - η < 0  \cap η - ζ < 0) = P (X < 0 \cap Y < 0) = \int_{\mathbb {R}} P(X < 0 \cap Y < 0 | Y = y)p_Y(y)dy$
$p_Y(y) = 1+y, P(X < 0 \cap Y < 0 | Y = y) = (y+1)^2/2$
So, $P (X < 0 \cap Y < 0) = \int_{-1}^0 ((y+1)^2/2) * (1+y) dy = 1/8$
But, the right answer is $1/6$.
What's wrong?

There are $6$ possible orders (ignoring events of probability $0$), each equally likely, so the answer is obviously $\frac 16$.

What is your motivation for moving from three independent random variables to two dependent random variables?   If you really want to solve this via integration, then it would clearly be easier to evaluate: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\xi<\eta<\zeta) &= \iiint_{\Bbb R^3}\mathbf 1_{x<y<z}, p_\zeta(z),p_\eta(y),p_\xi(x),\mathrm d x,\mathrm d y,\mathrm d z\[1ex] &=\int_0^1\int_0^z\int_0^y 1,\mathrm d x,\mathrm d y,\mathrm d z \end{align}$$

You evaluated $\mathsf P(X<0, Y<0, Y=y)$ rather than $\mathsf P(X<0, Y<0\mid Y=y)$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\xi-\eta<0, \eta-\zeta<0 , \eta-\zeta=y)&=\mathsf P(\xi<\eta,\zeta=\eta-y, -1<y<0)\\ &=\iint_{0<u<v<1, 0<v-y<1}\mathbf 1_{-1<y<0}\,\mathrm d u\,\mathrm d v\\ &= \iint_{-1<y<0<u<v<1+y<1}\mathrm d u\,\mathrm d v\\ &=\int_{-1<y<0<v<1+y<1}v\,\mathrm d v\\[1ex]  &= \tfrac 12 (1+y)^2\mathbf 1_{-1<y<0}\\[4ex]\mathsf P(X<0, Y<0) &=\int_\Bbb R \mathsf P(X<0, Y<0, Y=y)\,\mathrm d y\\ &=\int_{-1}^0\tfrac 12(1+y)^2\,\mathrm d y\\ &=\tfrac 16\end{align}$$
